# Mongodb express manual reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

books.insertOne is inserting null value instead of tmpId. Both console.log(tmpId) displaying correct value. How to fix it?

```
app.post('/logged/:login/addBook/confirm', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    var login = req.params.login;
    var id = parseInt(req.body.bId);
    var autor = req.body.bAutor;
    var tytul = req.body.bTytul;
    var ksi = req.body.libId;


    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Nawiązano połączenie z serwerem");

    var books = db.collection('books');
    var spis = db.collection('spisBibliotek');
    var tmpId;

        spis.find({"nazwa":{$eq: ksi}}).toArray(function(er1, r1){
          tmpId = new ObjectID(r1[0]._id);
          console.log(tmpId);
        });

          books.insertOne({id: id, autor: autor, tytul: tytul, ksiegarnia: tmpId}, function(er2,r2){
            console.log(tmpId);
        });
    res.redirect('/logged/'+login+'/addBook');
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that mongo operations are asynchronous. So your `books.insertOne` is executing before `spis.find` is done. You can use callbacks or promises to solve this but a simple solution could be:

```
spis.find({query: query}, (err, records)=>{
    if(!err) {
        books.insertOne(stuff)
    }
})
```

This is pseudo code obviously so you'll have to play with it a bit.

Also, the same goes for anything like `res.send`. That redirect will actually happen before your mongo operations are done. So you want to put it inside a callback.